# URLSession does not run second GET

Tags: swift, get, urlsession

I can't get my second "GET" task to work.

This is a beginner fight to learn Swift.

I'm working with the "thetvdb" API to get the series info and enumeration.
API info: https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger

The first step is to login and get the token with a "POST" to https://api.thetvdb.com/login.

The next is to "GET" the ID of the desired serie with the next function:

```swift
    func GetSerieID(theSerieName: String){

        refreshToken() //Refresh the token before anything

        let theURL = "https://api.thetvdb.com/search/series?name=" + theSerieName
        let url = URL(string: theURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") // the refreshed token

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data{
                // I use SwiftyJSON.swift to manage the JSON's
                let json = try? JSON(data: data)
                theJSONContent = json!["data"]

                // Manage the theJSONContent to get the ID

            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("httpResponse: " + String(httpResponse.statusCode) + " >>GetSerieID\n")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

The GetSerieID function works fenomenal, but the next GetSerieData function does not establish the URLSession, **it jumps to the return immediately!**

```swift
    func GetSerieData(theSerieID: String) -> JSON {

        refreshToken() //Refresh the token before anything

        var theJSONContent = JSON()

        let theURL = "https://api.thetvdb.com/series/" + theSerieID + "/episodes"
        let url = URL(string: theURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") // the refreshed token

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data{
                // I use SwiftyJSON.swift to manage the JSON's
                let json = try? JSON(data: data)
                theJSONContent = json!["data"]

            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("httpResponse: " + String(httpResponse.statusCode) + " >>GetSerieID\n")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        return theJSONContent
    }
```

The next is the request:

```swift
Printing description of request:
▿ https://api.thetvdb.com/series/300472/episodes
  ▿ url : Optional<URL>
    ▿ some : https://api.thetvdb.com/series/300472/episodes
  - cachePolicy : 0
  - timeoutInterval : 60.0
  - mainDocumentURL : nil
  - networkServiceType : __ObjC.NSURLRequest.NetworkServiceType
  - allowsCellularAccess : true
  ▿ httpMethod : Optional<String>
    - some : "GET"
  ▿ allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>
    ▿ some : 3 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : "Accept"
        - value : "application/json"
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : "Content-Type"
        - value : "application/json"
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : "Authorization"
        - value : "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5tokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentoken"
  - httpBody : nil
  - httpBodyStream : nil
  - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
  - httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

Both functions for "GET" are practically the same, just the URL changes.
It's surely something simple, but I'm stuck.

If I turn them over and call GetSerieData first and then GetSerieID, then the first one works again but not the second one.

It is clear that it is a problem by establishing the first connection with the GET, which does not end the session or something, but I can not find how to handle it.
In some version of the code, I added a "DELETE" just for try, but it didn't work either.

Can someone show me some light?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because this task is async, and its immediately returning. You need to add completion block.

```
func GetSerieData(theSerieID: String, completion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {

        refreshToken() //Refresh the token before anything

        var theJSONContent = JSON()

        let theURL = "https://api.thetvdb.com/series/" + theSerieID + "/episodes"
        let url = URL(string: theURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") // the refreshed token

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data{
                // I use SwiftyJSON.swift to manage the JSON's
                let json = try? JSON(data: data)
                theJSONContent = json!["data"]
                completion(theJSONContent)
            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("httpResponse: " + String(httpResponse.statusCode) + " >>GetSerieID\n")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: **I just tried it and it worked** I didn't know anything about "completion" and "@escaping" and it is very interesting! Thanks ;)

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to chain two methods. Call `GetSerieID` and when you will find `SerielID` call `GetSerieData`. This should work.